# Politicians and revolutionaries

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2nabaony)

**Across**
1. Jokes for children (4)
3. Key figures starting a religious service; they're often found in churches (6)
7. Where one might see Homer making *Odyssey*'s ending shorter, for starters (4)
8. Image of Yankee soldier very forcefully starting to evacuate from the East (6)
10. Female shooter arrived unprepared near Gulf state (11)
12. Surroundings of newly ordered vent broken by extreme athletes (11)
15. Abuse extreme elements in legislature being in the majority (6)
16. Prevent swapping Toyota's front and parking in parking space (4)
18. Hobo is talking to house band member (6)
19. US president not starting to get supporting votes (4)

**Down**
1. I am contracted to follow the debut of Khloé Kardashian (3)
2. Doctor West from Hollywood brought up fantasy (5)
4. Wrap leg around female sibling to show the placement of 1, 10 and 15 down politically, as well as here? (4,4)
5. A Chinese politician who has published several books on the core of diplomatic doctrine (5)
6. Quiet and coy, ultimately (3)
9. Detain pilfering man close to southern parts of Chesterfield? (8)
10. Revolutionary Guevara – he is supporting Cuba's leader (3)
11. Idiot to make sweater, perhaps in broadcast (3)
13. Revolutionary Ulyanov loved getting hold of large Swedish company (5)
14. Ticket for trendy cocktail dinner's opening missing (5)
15. Chairman's mother, the second-in-command (3)
17. Plums regularly cut to find sign of infection (3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grid:

> [image: completed crossword]

Across:

> 1. **Jokes** for **children** (4) - **KIDS** - double definition
>  3. Key figures starting a religious service; **they're often found in churches** (6) - **ALTARS** - ALT (key) + A R(-eligious) S(-ervice)
>  7. **Where one might see Homer** making Odyssey's ending shorter, for starters (4) - [**MOE'S**](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Moe%27s_Tavern) - M(-aking) O(-dyssey's) E(-nding) S(-horter)
>  8. **Image** of Yankee soldier very forcefully starting to evacuate from the East (6) - **EFFIGY** - (Y (Yankee) + GI (soldier) + FF (very forcefully) + E(-vacuate))<
>  10. **Female shooter** arrived unprepared near Gulf state (11) - **CAMERAWOMAN** - CAME (arrived) + RAW (unprepared) + OMAN (Gulf state)
>  12. **Surroundings** of newly ordered vent broken by extreme athletes (11) - **ENVIRONMENT** - VENT* broken by IRONMEN (extreme athletes)
>  15. **Abuse** extreme elements in legislature being in the majority (6) - **MOLEST** - L(-egislatur)E being in MOST (the majority)
>  16. **Prevent** swapping Toyota's front and parking in parking space (4) - **STOP** - SPOT (parking space) swapping T(-oyota) and P (parking)
>  18. Hobo is talking to house **band member** (6) - **OBOIST** - substring of hOBO IS Talking
>  19. US president not starting to get **supporting votes** (4) - **AYES** - (-h)AYES

Down:

> 1. I am contracted to follow the debut of Khloé **Kardashian** (3) - **KIM** - K(-hloé) + I'M (I am contracted)
>  2. Doctor West from Hollywood brought up **fantasy** (5) - **DREAM** - DR (doctor) + [MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mae_West)< (West from Hollywood)
>  4. Wrap leg around female sibling to show **the placement of 1, 10 and 15 down politically, as well as here?** (4,4) - **LEFT WING** - LEG around F (female) TWIN (sibling); KIM
>  5. A Chinese politician who has published several books on the core of diplomatic **doctrine** (5) - **AXIOM** - A + XI (Chinese politician who has published several books) + (-dipl)OM(-atic)
>  6. **Quiet and coy, ultimately** (3) - **SHY** - SH (quiet) + (-co)Y &lit!
>  9. Detain pilfering man close to southern **parts of [Chesterfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chesterfield_sofa)**? (8) - **ARMRESTS** - ARREST (detain) pilfering M (man) + S (southern)
>  10. **Revolutionary Guevara** – he is supporting Cuba's leader (3) - **CHE** - HE supporting C(-uba)
>  11. **Idiot** to make sweater, perhaps in broadcast (3) - **NIT** - homophone of KNIT (make sweater, perhaps)
>  13. Revolutionary Ulyanov loved getting hold of **large Swedish company** (5) - **VOLVO** - Reversed substring of ulyanOV LOVed
>  14. **Ticket** for trendy cocktail dinner's opening missing (5) - **ENTRY** - TRENDY* with D(-inner) missing
>  15. **Chairman**'s mother, the second-in-command (3) - **MAO** - MA (mother) + (-c)O(-mmand)
>  17. Plums regularly cut to find **sign of infection** (3) - **PUS** - P(-l)U(-m)S